# What is the difference between (!file) and (!file.is_open())?

Tags: c++, fstream

What is the difference between `if(!file)` and `if(!file.is_open())`?
I use them for checking if a file has successfully been opened/read or not.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream file;

// first one
if (!file) 
   cout<<"File is not opened"<<endl;
else 
   . . .

//second one
if (!file.is_open()) 
   cout<<"File is not opened"<<endl;
else 
   . . .
}
```

Comment: `!file.is_open` is ill-formed, you probably meant `!file.is_open()`

Comment: yeap sorry, i forgot to write the () at the back.

Comment: If the open fails, `failbit` is set, so the tests are effectively equivalent for open. see [std::basic_ifstream<CharT,Traits>::basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)

Answer (score 3):

The c++ documentation explains that [`operator!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!)

> Returns `true` if an error has occurred on the associated stream. Specifically, returns `true` if `badbit` or `failbit` is set in `rdstate()`

On the other hand, [`is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/is_open)

> Checks if the file stream has an associated file. Returns `true` if the file stream has an associated file, `false` otherwise

If you want to know if the file successfully opened, use `is_open()`. It is more expressive of your intentions as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation, you'll see that [operator!](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) returns whether an error has occurred. While [is_open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/is_open) returns whether the stream has an associated file. Two *very different* things.

Comment: Oh wow it even has `operator!`. Why does it have both (bool and not)?

Comment: `is_open`, technically, returns its function adress.

Comment: @StackDanny It returns `bool`, so *no*, it does *not* return an address.

Comment: @Timo [operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) returns `!fail()`.

Comment: so do you mean if to check whether the file has error to open or not, i have to use operator ! ; if to check whether the file is associated, so i have to use is_open() ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl don't `operator!` and `! operator bool` yield the same result?

Comment: nvm `fail()` checks failbit and badbit, `operator!` only checks failbit. Seems weired.

Comment: The truth table at the end of [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) shows that `operator bool` is inverse to `operator!` so why is it explicitly defined in the first place.

Comment: If the `open()` call returns a null pointer, sets `setstate(failbit)`, see [std::basic_ifstream<CharT,Traits>::basic_ifstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream), so if the file open isn't successful, `failbit` is set for the `!file` test and will test appropriately.